# mongodb disable write access (while db migration)

Tags: mongodb

I want to migrate from one cluster to another. So I'm goint go make a backup with mongodump and mongorestore. Db is not so big, so I would like to disable writes on source db before the start to exclude accidental writes from apps.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two similar options available, based on user permissions.

1. For the user which your application uses to connect to the DB (let's call it *applicationConnUser*), change its permissions: for example if it currently has the [readWrite role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#readWrite), [revoke](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.revokeRolesFromUser/) that and [grant](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.grantRolesToUser/) the [read role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#read) instead.
2. Set up a different user - leave *applicationConUser* unchanged and create a new account *applicationConUserReadOnly* to which you grant the read role - and reconfigure your application to connect with this account instead.

Note that your application may not react helpfully when its normal operations cannot write to the database; depending on how it is coded, it may crash out as soon as it gets a db error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to change permissions remotely via cli?

Comment: Yes, all the commands to do with granting and revoking roles can be executed through the command-line mongo shell.

Answer (score 0):

For those using more up-to-date versions of MongoDB you may want to take a look at [`db.fsynclock()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.fsyncLock/)